# Why is Secure Boot in an ECU required when there is Secure Flashing capabilities?

Tags: flash, secure-boot

it seems state of the art that the autmotive electronical Control units (ECUs) contain security features as Secure Flashing and Secure Boot. For secure flashing, each new software to be programmed is verified by performing signature verification before it is installed.

Why does one then need secure boot, where checksums are being calculated to verify that the application has not been altered? To alter the software, one would have to reflash it, but for that, secure flashing feature is implemented. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: There is a difference between a) restricting what the *intended method* of replacing the stored software will write, and b) restricting the *effective* set of requirements of what stored software will be executed, regardless of how it was written. Those restrictions have different limitations, you appear to assume they were equal.

Comment: But any software that has been successfully flashed will be executed